# want to append text-block in grid dynamically Wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, chatbot, textblock

i want to create Chatbot and use a Responce grid as Main chat area.whenever i used my method with different string then everytime my method override the previous textblock but i want to append my next textblock below the first one like whatsapp and any other messenger.

that is my xaml code

```
<Grid x:Name="Responce" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="315" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="422" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
```

and that one is my c# method that create textblock and add it in grid.

```
private void CustomerReply(string sms)
        {
            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            var textBlock = new TextBlock();
            var bc = new BrushConverter();
            textBlock.Text = sms;          
            textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            textBlock.FontSize = 12;
            textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
            textBlock.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
            textBlock.Background = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#e0fcc4");
            textBlock.FontFamily = new FontFamily("Helvetica Neue");
            textBlock.FontStretch = FontStretches.UltraExpanded;
            textBlock.FontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
            textBlock.Typography.NumeralStyle = FontNumeralStyle.OldStyle;
            textBlock.Typography.SlashedZero = true;
            sp.Children.Add(textBlock);
            Responce.Children.Add(sp);
```

enter image description here
that i the actual output with problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XAML:

```
...
<StackPanel x:Name="RootStack">
</StackPanel>
...
```

Code behind:

```
private void CustomerReply(string sms)
{
    var textBlock = new TextBlock {Text = sms};
    //add other values here
    RootStack.Children.Add(textBlock);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `ListBox` and an `ObservableCollection` instead. It's easier and will allow you to scroll the content/messages by default.
Setting `ListBox.IsHitTestVisible` to `False` will disable selection of the `ListBox` items and remove the list look and feel.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty SmsCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SmsCollection",
    typeof(ObservableCollection<string>),
    typeof(MainWindow),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<string>)));

  public ObservableCollection<string> SmsCollection
  {
    get => (ObservableCollection<string>) GetValue(MainWindow.SmsCollectionProperty); 
    set => SetValue(MainWindow.SmsCollectionProperty, value); 
  }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.SmsCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  }

  private void CustomerReply(string sms)
  {
    // Since SmsCollection is a ObservablecCollection, add/remove/move will be reflected in the UI immediately.
    this.SmsCollection.Add(sms);
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}, Path=SmsCollection}" 
           IsHitTestVisible="False">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                   Background="#e0fcc4"
                   FontFamily="Helvetica Neue"
                   ...
                       />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```

Comment: Why avoiding `DataContext` setup? Maybe it may look easier than adding DP.

Comment: MainWindow.xaml show error when i used MainWindow.xaml code.    @aepot

Comment: `"{Biding ReelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}, Path=SmsCollection}"` two typos here: change to `"{Binding SmsCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=MainWindow}}"`

Comment: @aepot Thank you for your hint. I have fixed the typos. I know that the data binding will work without the dependency property. But since it is generally highly recommended to implement every property that serves as a binding source as a `DependencyProperty` I chose to go with it in order to advocate good coding practices. Using `DependencyProperty` offers the best binding performance followed by `INotifyPropertyChanged` and using a plain CLR property (which will introduce a memory leak in certain scenarios).

Comment: @aepot Indeed, setting the `DataContext` to the `MainWindow` itself, would simplify the bindings that have properties of `MainWindow` as their source.

Comment: @AhmadKabeer you have to import your namespace where `MainWindow` is defined and then reference the type in XAML. For example if your `MainWindow` class is defined in a namespace `Main`, then you have to add `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Main"` to the root `Window` element. This will import this namespace and create an alias called `local`. Then qualify the type by using this alias: `"{Binding ...{RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow} ...}"`. This should fix the errors. You generally have to do this for every custom type when using XAML (`xmlns`) and when using C# (`using`) too.

Comment: @AhmadKabeer If this doesn't help, please let me know the exact error you are getting, so that I'm able to help you to fix it.

Comment: @AhmadKabeer You can simplify the binding when you add the following line to the constructor: `this.DataContext = this;`. Then the binding on the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property would become: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SmsCollection}" ... />`. This is a valid option, if you don't plan to use any other data source as the data context of your control.

Comment: @BionicCode Correct and good point. But full INPC implementation anyway looks easier than DP **:D** I follow DP in `UserControl` or something. In `Window` I prefer `DataContext` and ViewModel even with [`PropertyChangedArgsCache`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Core/blob/master/src/Nito.Mvvm.Core/PropertyChangedEventArgsCache.cs). I'm not afraid of `Reflection` used by `Binding`. Maximum of properties in my VM exceeds 50 in the largest windows. Thus, it doesn't matter in performance point of view: DP or `DataContext`.

Comment: @aepot Yes, I also prefer to use a data model as bindng source. but I didn't want overcomplicate the solution, since the OP is obviously not following the MVVM pattern. In this context control properties will usually serve as binding target rather than as a binding source. For a binding target a dependency property is mandatory. The performance impact of reflection comes into account when using a large number of bindings especially when using plain CLR properties (without `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementing source object).

Comment: @aepot I personally don't care about the effort. I am a lazy programmer, so I use Resharper. I generally highly recommend to use templates to create dependency properties, attached properties, or INPC properties or other repetitive code or code patterns. But you are right, they look more difficult to implement.

Comment: @aepot Thanks for the link. Do you really think creating the event args instance is expensive enough to cache their instances? At least it should be cheap compared to using reflection. But if you go high performance this might be a consideration, especially when properties change at a higher frequency.

Comment: @BionicCode The creaition of the Args instances is not the thing that's have high impact on performance but the cache saves memory and **makes less work for GC** (triple win). It is something like easy implement-and-forget and doesn't affect anything in project because I have INPC implementation in a separate class and I derive from it everywhere. I like garbage-free things like `ArrayPool`. When i started garbage-free optimizations, I saved ~25% memory and reduced GC collections count ~twice, and definetly improved the performance. But performance wasn't reason of that work.